# String in C programming

Tags: c, visual-studio

Hi I have a question about subsequent code in C:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name[10];
    printf("Enter your name: \n");
    scanf_s("%s", &name);

    printf("Your name is: %s", name);


    return 0;
}
```

It works perfectly using CodeBlocks, but using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 it just doesn't work.
This warning is always shown:

```
Warning C4473   'scanf_s' : not enough arguments passed for format string
```

Could you please give me a hint on what's going on?

NOTE: In Visual Studio I always use scanf_s instead of scanf.

Comment: `scanf_s()` is not a standard function and requires extra parameters. [Read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx).

Comment: Also you should pass `name` not `&name` to scan into.

Comment: "*In Visual Studio I always use scanf_s instead of scanf.*" Why?

Comment: I'm still confused as to why it would work on command line instead of VS. If I understand correctly, you _change the function_ when you go from one to the other? In that case, I have the same questions as @alk

Comment: @alk because vs2015 will refuse to compile the code. @PinkP use `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before `#include <stdio.h>` and other 'include' files to disable deprecation and use `scanf()` normally.

Comment: One more question, what is the difference between name and &name?

Answer (score 1):

"scanf_s" needs an extra parameter that is buffer size.

for example:

```
scanf_s("%s", name, 1024);
```